# What is "Total Functional Programming"?

Tags: programming-languages, functional-programming

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_functional_programming) has this to say:

> Total functional programming (also
>   known as strong functional
>   programming, to be contrasted with
>   ordinary, or weak functional
>   programming) is a programming paradigm
>   which restricts the range of programs
>   to those which are provably
>   terminating.

and

> These restrictions mean that total
>   functional programming is not
>   Turing-complete. However, the set of
>   algorithms which can be used is still
>   huge. For example, any algorithm which
>   has had an asymptotic upper bound
>   calculated for it can be trivially
>   transformed into a
>   provably-terminating function by using
>   the upper bound as an extra argument
>   which is decremented upon each
>   iteration or recursion.

There is also a Lambda The Ultimate Post about a paper on [Total Functional Programming](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/2003).

I hadn't come across that until last week on a mailing list.

Are there any more resources, references or any example implementations that you know of?

Comment: I think that at this point is just an idea with no implementation. I'd love to be proved wrong though. Sorry, didn't check LtU's post before writing the answer I deleted.

Comment: Hah, I'd never thought about that trivial transformation. That's pretty awesome.

Comment: @VinkoVrsalovic this is implemented in Coq currently (and was in '08, afaik).  Now, whether Coq is used or not is a different story ;-)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If I understood that correctly, Total Functional Programming means just that: Programming with Total Functions. If I remember my math courses correctly, a Total Function is a function which is defined over its entire domain, a Partial Function is one which has "holes" in its definition.

Now, if you have a function which for some input value `v` goes into an infinite recursion or an infinite loop or in general doesn't terminate in some other fashion, then your function isn't defined for `v`, and thus partial, i.e. not total.

Total Functional Programming doesn't allow you to write such a function. All functions always return a result for all possible inputs; and the type checker ensures that this is the case.

My guess is that this vastly simplifies error handling: there aren't any.

The downside is already mentioned in your quote: it's not Turing-complete. E.g. an Operating System is essentially a giant infinite loop. Indeed, we do not *want* an Operating System to terminate, we call this behaviour a "crash" and yell at our computers about it!

Comment: the big thing this doesn't allow is unbounded minimalization. I know sometimes these styles also allow programs that provably never terminate, as those also can be useful(e.g. operating systems). The functions that are tough to deal with are those that might terminate, as you can't know if your program is going to give you the answer(or halt).

Comment: I disagree, if you read the paper and post, you can have a total function that "runs forever," it's simply a coinductively defined function, not an inductively defined function, this is exactly _how_ you'd write an operating system using this method of programming.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski does inductive mean recursive? So coinductive means corecursive? Does that mean a total functional programming still allows non-termination by distinguishing between data and codata?

Comment: The inductive / recursive distinction is not really well defined, the way I differentiate them is via logical sorts (e.g., "Set" vs "Prop" in Coq).  Total functional programming allows nontermination by using codata, but only with the constraint that that codata is productive (i.e., any finite observation produces something to "look" at).

Comment: This answer is factually incorrect. The "function" that allegedly cannot be written is not a function. It may well be that for some inputs, a particular algorithm delivers an infinite computational process. Many total programming languages allow the construction of infinite processes by coinduction. Operating Systems should be total coinductive programs: i.e., always live. A total programming language can explain exactly what potentially infinite process Turing-machine execution is: it just can't promise that it's always finite, because it isn't. Partial languages are not good at promises.

Answer (score 14):

While this is an old question, I think that none of the answers so far mention the real *motivation* for total functional programming, which is this:

If programs are proofs, and proofs are programs, then programs which have 'holes' don't make any sense as proofs, and introduce logical inconsistency.

Basically, if a proof is a program, an infinite loop can be used to prove *anything*.  This is really bad, and provides much of the motivation for why we might want to program totally.  Other answers tend to not account for the flip side of the paper.  While the languages are *techincally* not turing complete, you can recover a lot of interesting programs by using co-inductive definitions and functions.  We're very prone to think of *inductive* data, but *codata* serves an important purpose in these languages, where you can totally define a definition which is infinite (and when doing real computation which terminates, you will potentially use only a finite piece of this, or maybe not if you're writing an operating system!).

It is also of note that most proof assistants work based on this principle, Coq, for example.

Comment: It's true that an inconsistency gives your logical system AIDs, but for programmers (and the title of this thread is "programming"), it's not the end of the world. It just means you need to be much more careful when reasoning about your system. If you can have non-terminating terms, then you can't (necessarily) replace n - n with 0. (It erases a termination effect, which may or may not be kosher). However, programmers tend not to care about corner cases when they can be written off. Maybe the case is exceedingly rare or unlikely and the application sufficiently non-mission-critical.

Comment: @Tac-Tics you're right, I should have clarified that "logical inconsistency" doesn't map directly to "program badness" in a realistic sense.  This is why, for example, most people don't write code in Coq: because the edge cases that crop up in functional specs often just don't matter enough to justify the extra time spent proving all the properties of your programs!

Answer (score 10):

Charity is another language that guarantees termination:
http://pll.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/charity1/www/home.html

Hume is a language with 4 levels. The outer level is Turing complete and the innermost layer guarantees termination:
  http://www-fp.cs.st-andrews.ac.uk/hume/report/