# How to write 2**n - 1 as a recursive function?

Tags: python, recursion

I need a function that takes n and returns **2<sup>n</sup> - 1** . It sounds simple enough, but the function has to be recursive. So far I have just 2<sup>n</sup>:

```
def required_steps(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return 2 * req_steps(n-1)
```

The exercise states: "You can assume that the parameter n is always a positive integer and greater than 0"

Comment: Just for the record, it should be vastly more efficient to do it like a normal person with a shift and subtract.  Python integers are arbitrary width so `1 << n` can't overflow.  This seems to be an exercise in inventing a way to decompose `(1<<n) - 1` into multiple steps, perhaps setting each bit one at a time like some answers show.

Comment: As some general rules of thumbs, you should try to see if `f(n+1)` or `f(2n)` can be written in terms of `f(n)`. In this case, both can be done using exponential rules and a bit of algebra (pun unintended).

Comment: Must your function take only one argument?  May it take two arguments where the second argument has a default value?

Comment: `def fn(n): if n == 0: return 1; return (2 << n) - fn(0); # technically recursive`

Comment: @MooseBoys Perfect example of how silly this exercise is. It's more about reverse-engineering what the professor is asking for than actually learning anything deep.

Comment: @Carl I look forward to your exercise to teach students recursion that is not "silly" and can be done by a beginner in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @Voo: Not Carl, but please list me everything that is contained in `C:\MyFolder`

Comment: @Flater And now your simple algorithm course exercise has to deal with platform differences, complex test setups and filesystem libraries. That will really help the students learn recursion better.

Comment: @Flater I assume you're just being contrarian and don't really believe that it's sane to require *filesystem libraries* to teach students the basics of recursion. But this is completely offtopic anyhow.

Comment: @Voo: Dependency or not is irrelevant for an exercise which purely focuses on teaching the concept of recursion. I could make a basic mocked set of classes/methods that students could use. You're focusing on something that is completely besides the point of the exercise. Using file system navigation is a good example because **students generally understand the inherently recurrent nature of folders and files** (i.e. folders can be nested in each other nigh indefinitely)

Comment: @Voo, on a POSIX system, you'd just need `opendir()`, `readdir()`, (`closedir()`, ) and `chdir()`. It would be easy to provide a sample function for listing the contents of one directory to build on. Anyway, it doesn't have to be the filesystem, any tree-like data structure in memory would also work (and tie the discussion to data structures, which might be good, or not.)

Comment: @Flater So you're saying you're *focusing* on teaching recursion by requiring a whole set of helper classes instead of asking students to write a single recursive function to teach them recursion and how to decompose functions? Any CS student will just as well understand the inherent recursive nature of a power or fibonacci function (that is after all how those are usually defined in your math course anyhow). Anyhow, no point continuing to go completely off-topic here, this should all be deleted.

Comment: @Voo No I'm saying that you can teach recursion by showing a recursive data structure. I have no idea why you struggle grasping this.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`2**n -1` is also **1+2+4+...+2<sup>n-1</sup>** which can made into a single recursive function (without the second one to subtract 1 from the power of 2).

**Hint**: 1+2*(1+2*(...))

Solution below, don't look if you want to try the hint first.

---

This works if `n` is guaranteed to be greater than zero (as was actually promised in the problem statement):

```
def required_steps(n):
    if n == 1: # changed because we need one less going down
        return 1
    return 1 + 2 * required_steps(n-1)
```

A more robust version would handle zero and negative values too:

```
def required_steps(n):
    if n < 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be non-negative")
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    return 1 + 2 * required_steps(n-1)
```

(Adding a check for non-integers is left as an exercise.)

Comment: but `required_steps(0)` now causes infinite recursion

Comment: `2^0 - 1` == 0. Add another `if` for that case.

Comment: We didn't get any possible values for n, so I changed as little as possible. I could also add recursive negative, but why? You should always test the code you take from SO and other sources anyway, so you should add any edge cases you need then.

Comment: @h4z3 do you know what a [total function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10875724/633183) is? Simply throwing more code at it is a naive solution.

Comment: @user633183 Yes, I know what a total function is. Do you? Because it won't ever be a total function. Nor are the other answers total functions. And yes, more code would be needed to make them total functions. - As I said, we have no domain. What should we assume our domain is? Even if it's just `int`, we don't know what to do when n<0. Calculate? Throw an error? Return 0? In this case, we only can do a partial function (define it for things we know what the result is).

Comment: The base case in the OP’s code is `0` and uses `n - 1` for the subproblem. A domain of [Natural Numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) seems like a good fit.

Comment: Thank you so much! In my humble opinion, this is the best solution for my specific problem. I didn't state possible values for n, really sorry! I know that is kinda important... the exercise states:

"You can assume that the parameter n is always a positive integer and greater than 0"

Comment: @h4z3 Thank you's point is that you wouldn't need *additional* code; you just need to change the base case. `required_steps(1) == 1 + 2*required_steps(0) == 1 + 2 * 0 == 1`.

Comment: @Thankyou The original post says that the function can assume the parameter is always greater than `0`.   Although this answer is not as robust as we'd like, it's correct because it fits within the assumptions of the exercise.   Of course, I'd make the change chepner suggests.

Comment: @Spencer, better? :)

Comment: (too bad the spoiler notation doesn't work with code)

Comment: It does even work with negative numbers: `(f(n+1) + 1) / 2 - 1` Things just get ugly when you use fractional numbers ...

Answer (score 36):

To solve a problem with a recursive approach you would have to find out how you can define the function with a given input in terms of the same function with a different input. In this case, since `f(n) = 2 * f(n - 1) + 1`, you can do:

```
def required_steps(n):
    return n and 2 * required_steps(n - 1) + 1
```

so that:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(required_steps(i))
```

outputs:

```
0
1
3
7
15
```

Answer (score 9):

You can extract the really recursive part to another function

```
def f(n):
    return required_steps(n) - 1
```

Or you can set a flag and define just when to subtract

```
def required_steps(n, sub=True):
    if n == 0: return 1
    return 2 * required_steps(n-1, False) - sub
```

---

```
>>> print(required_steps(10))
1023
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a placeholder to remember original value of n and then for the very first step i.e. `n == N`, return `2^n-1`

```py
n = 10
# constant to hold initial value of n
N = n
def required_steps(n, N):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == N:
        return 2 * required_steps(n-1, N) - 1
    return 2 * required_steps(n-1, N)

required_steps(n, N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an additional parameter for the result, `r` -

```
def required_steps (n = 0, r = 1):
  if n == 0:
    return r - 1
  else:
    return required_steps(n - 1, r * 2)

for x in range(6):
  print(f"f({x}) = {required_steps(x)}")

# f(0) = 0
# f(1) = 1
# f(2) = 3
# f(3) = 7
# f(4) = 15
# f(5) = 31
```

You can also write it using bitwise left shift, `<<` -

```
def required_steps (n = 0, r = 1):
  if n == 0:
    return r - 1
  else:
    return required_steps(n - 1, r << 1)
```

The output is the same

Comment: Unnecessary to involve bitwise operations for a simple multiplication exercise.. not readable at all. Also, no need for the `else` clause in either function

Comment: The only difference is changing `r * 2` to `r << 1` and that is "not readable at all"? 

Comment: Inventing a 2nd parameter just turns this into a loop that shifts left `n` times and then subtracts 1.  Seems even less elegant then necessary, although the whole thing is an exercise in inefficiency vs. `(1<<n) - 1`.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Moving the state into an accumulator parameter is *the* standard way of transforming a recursive call into a tail-recursive call. Now, unfortunately, Python doesn't support Proper Tail Calls, not even Proper Tail Recursion, but that doesn't mean that this isn't a useful technique to learn so that you can apply it in other languages that *do* implement Proper Tail Calls or at least Proper Tail Recursion.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Yes, but in this case it's hard to disguise the fact that it would be *more* natural as a loop.  Maybe it's just that I spend so much time on assembly language and performance, but writing a "loop" by using tail-recursion seems pointless in an imperative language when you could just write a loop.  Or perhaps what bothers me about this answer is just the choice of how to decompose: into one-at-a-time shifts and then a final subtract as the basecase.  Probably a combination of both.

Answer (score -1):

One way to get the offset of "-1" is to apply it in the return from the first function call using an argument with a default value, then explicitly set the offset argument to zero during the recursive calls.

```
def required_steps(n, offset = -1):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return offset + 2 * required_steps(n-1,0)
```

Answer (score -1):

On top of all the awesome answers given earlier, below will show its implementation with inner functions.

```py
def outer(n):
    k=n
    def p(n):
        if n==1:
            return 2
        if n==k:
            return 2*p(n-1)-1
        return 2*p(n-1)
    return p(n)

n=5
print(outer(n))
```

Basically, it is assigning a global value of n to k and recursing through it with appropriate comparisons.